# use AKAI mic on Laptop

Tags: microphone, laptop

I do not know about audio.

I found an AKAI microphone and want to use it with my laptop. The AKAI microphone's jack is probably a 6 or 6.5 mm.

Can I use this microphone to record on my laptop? If I could, what software/hardware do I need because my laptop only have 2 audio in/out for 3.5 mm jack.

I attach a photo of the AKAI microphone.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a basic level all you need is an adapter to take your existing jack to the 3.5mm your laptop has.

If your laptop runs windows or Linux then you already have recording software built in, but for a more fuller featured application, Audacity is a popular choice. Once you have more experience you may want a DAW, but that isn't necessary at this stage.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't been around so sorry for the late reply. I guess I'll get myself an adapter like you suggest and plug it in to see if it works.